# GAE SDK 1.6.4 on Mac with django-nonrel: syncdb won't create the datastore file

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, django-nonrel

first question from newbie. Haven't needed to post a question for months now -- so many great answers already posted. I am stuck on this one, though.

Developing on a Mac, Python 2.7, Django with the django-nonrel project, GAE datastore. Up to and including GAE SDK 1.6.3, all goodness. After upgrading to GAE SDK 1.6.4, noticed 3 strange things:

1. Dev server (python manage.py runserver) fails immediately with "Error: No module named webob." No other errors or output. I rooted around under /usr/local/google_appengine/lib/... and, indeed, no module named webob. There are two close matches -- webob_0_9 and webob_1_1_1. I made a symlink webob -> webob_1_1_1 to get past the error.
2. Startup messages from the dev server include an INFO: message that the SDK version is later than the advertised version. Google has 1.6.4 on their download site, so not seeing how my 1.6.4 is later than the latest.
3. Django's syncdb command (python manage.py syncdb) will no longer create the .gaedata/datastore file. It says it's creating tables, it prompts me for the superuser creds, it even says it installed a bunch of objects from my fixture file. It gives no errors, but when it completes, it has done none of these things -- the .gaedata/datastore file doesn't even exist.

Prior to 1.6.4, syncdb worked great, including loading fixture data. I tried starting a fresh project with only bare bones files in it and a simple model (one class having one field) to see if some complexity I had introduced might be the cause of the problem. Even in simple-land, syncdb wouldn't create the datastore.

My only solution was to fall back to GAE SDK 1.6.3 -- everything works once again. Anyone else seeing similar symptoms with SDK 1.6.4? Are there obvious diagnostic steps I should be taking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Fixed in latest django-nonrel. Either sync to latest code, or manually integrate this pull request:
   https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine/pull/24
2. Haven't seen this problem, don't know.
3. There's a workaround, but it's not merged into the master branch yet, you'll have to manually integrate the changes.
   https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine/pull/25

Comment: Thanks for quick response! Obviously I need to start paying attention to the django-nonrel activity at github. At github I see django-nonrel/django and also django-nonrel/django-nonrel which in turn has its own django subdir. Which 'django' subdir is my project supposed to end up with?

Comment: I recommend sticking with django-nonrel for now.  The django folder is an attempt to get it integrated with django 1.4.  it's probably a while before that's done.  And while you're at it, you want to accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark :)

Comment: Answer gratefully accepted. (The hollow checkmark is tastefully discreet -- sorry for missing it completely.)